# How do I move both files and folders to the specified directory?

Tags: python, shutil

There is a code that moves files from one directory to another, but it doesn't move folders.

```
import os,glob
import shutil

inpath = str5
outpath = str6

os.chdir(inpath)
for file in glob.glob("*.*"):

    shutil.move(inpath+'/'+file,outpath)
```

How to make it move both files and folders to the specified directory?

Comment: `glob` for `"*"`, not just `"*.*"`. That is, `glob.glob("*")`

Answer (score 1):

`*.*` selects files that have an extension, so it omits sub-folders.

Use `*` to select files and folders.

Then you should see your desired result.

```
for file in glob.glob("*"):
    shutil.move(inpath+'/'+file,outpath)
```

Comment: Hi, the directory is trying to move itself into itself, is it possible to add an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.listdir` to get all the files and folders in a directory.

```
import os
import shutil

def move_file_and_folders(inpath, outpath):
    for filename in os.listdir(inpath):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(inpath, filename), os.path.join(outpath, filename))
```

In your case,

```
inpath = <specify the source>
outpath = <specify the destination>
move_file_and_folders(inpath, outpath)
```

Comment: In the "Downloads" directory, there is a folder in which there is another folder with the current date, to which I want to move all the files from the downloads.


It is still trying to move itself, but now I get an access error. Although the launch occurs with all rights.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path/CleanDay.py", line 54, in <module>
    move_file_and_folders(inpath, outpath)
  File "Path/CleanDay.py", line 53, in move_file_and_folders
    shutil.move(os.path.join(inpath, filename), os.path.join(outpath, filename))
  File "C:\Users\Kiya229\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 814, in move
    raise Error("Cannot move a directory '%s' into itself"
shutil.Error: Cannot move a directory 'C:\Users\Kiya229\Downloads\Folder' into itself 'Folder\2021-12-28 18-13\Folder'.

Comment: You can add an if to ignore that particular destination alone